# bash loop files echo .sh file and no extension file

Tags: bash

i wantg to echo all files that have .sh or no extension
but i have only *.sh file, not no extension file
this is my code:

```
files=./*
for file in $files
do
    if [[ $file == *.sh || $file != *.* ]]; then
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

why me condition

```
$file != *.*
```

not work ?
thanks in advance

Comment: ok but for no extension file like "myfile" ?
i want my function return "myfile.sh" and "myfile"

Comment: Works for me.  Example: `file=abc; [[ $file == *.sh || $file != *.* ]] && echo true` outputs _true_ in my bash.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have `.` in `./*` which matches `*.*`.

You should use :

```
for file in *
do
    if [[ $file == *.sh || $file != *.* ]]; then
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
```